# Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Below is the error I am getting on my shiny App. I want to get a graph on pageviews of certain pages of my blog. I am using RGA (google analytics package also)

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

my code is :

```
#ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  textInput("text", label = h3("City"), value = "Enter city name..."),

  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(12, tableOutput("table1")))

))
#server.R

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  content_data <- reactive({

    ga$getData(id, start.date=Sys.Date()-10, end.date=Sys.Date()-1,
                                metrics = "ga:pageViews",
                                dimensions = "ga:day",
                                filter =  paste0("ga:pagePath=@/tp/", input$text))
  }) 
 output$table1 <- renderTable[{content_data()}]
 })
```

Comment: 1) `renderTable[{content_data()}]` look bad --use `(` unstead of `[` .. 2) what do you want with that string `ga$getData` ? in RGA examle i saw only `get_ga(` 3) to get id you need `authorize()`
    `ga_profiles <- list_profiles()`

Comment: Thanks Got it. 
Brackets did it.